# What is the display parameter in DynamicLayout

Tags: android, dynamiclayout

The [`DynamicLayout` constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/DynamicLayout.html#DynamicLayout(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.text.TextPaint,%20int,%20android.text.Layout.Alignment,%20float,%20float,%20boolean,%20android.text.TextUtils.TruncateAt,%20int)) has a `base` parameter and a `display` parameter, both of which are `CharSequence`. ([`StaticLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/StaticLayout.html), by comparison, lacks this.)

```
DynamicLayout (CharSequence base, 
                CharSequence display, 
                TextPaint paint, 
                int width, 
                Layout.Alignment align, 
                float spacingmult, 
                float spacingadd, 
                boolean includepad, 
                TextUtils.TruncateAt ellipsize, 
                int ellipsizedWidth)
```

What does the `display` parameter mean? The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/DynamicLayout.html#DynamicLayout(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.text.TextPaint,%20int,%20android.text.Layout.Alignment,%20float,%20float,%20boolean,%20android.text.TextUtils.TruncateAt,%20int))  says nothing. I looked into the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/text/DynamicLayout.java) and I see both an [`mBase` and an `mDisplay`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/text/DynamicLayout.java#109) but I can't figure out the difference between them. My best guess is that `display` has something to do with ellipsized text, though why one would need to pass in two different character sequences is beyond me.

The [most basic constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/DynamicLayout.html#DynamicLayout(java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.text.TextPaint,%20int,%20android.text.Layout.Alignment,%20float,%20float,%20boolean)) lacks the `display` parameter (it is set equal to `base` in the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/text/DynamicLayout.java#50)), so I assume `display` provides some sort of optional functionality. What is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`TextView`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java) uses it with different arguments when there's a [`TransformationMethod`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/TransformationMethod.html) attached, such as in the case of `<EditText android:password="true"/>`.

`DynamicLayout` attaches a change listener to the base text, but otherwise performs all the layout on the transformed text. Thus, when the base text is edited, it will be notified, and will update the layout on the affected range in the transformed text.

When `base` = `display`, it's watching for changes and computing layout on the same `CharSequence`. Which is the expected behavior for non-transformed text.